# How to solve these errors in validation?

Tags: java

As a new class exercise I was ask to do a "class" that resembles a car functionality using certain requirements.

The class should use these attributes:

```
state (int)
fuel (int)
maxspeed (int)
```

The state are the following:

```
0 = turned off
1 = stopped
2 = accelerating
3 = not functional
4 = no fuel
```

I must create the following methods:

```
"accelerate", it should receive a number as speed
"brake"
"crash"
```

Now, the validations are as follow:

```
The car can not accelerate if it is turned off (0), not functional (3), or no fuel (4).

It cannot accelerate more than maximum speed.

When there's a crash the car goes not functional (3)

Every time the car accelerates it loses 2 of fuel units
```

**Now, the validations might seem simple but somehow I'm having trouble on validating when the car accelerates or not. On my code the car keeps accelerating even after a crash or without fuel. It also changes the state after a crash, being turned off or when without fuel.**

This is my code:

```
private int state;
private int fuel;
private int speed;


 public car() // constructor
{
    this.state = 1;
    this.fuel = 30;
    this.speed = 0;
    int Maxspeed = 200;
}

public void setState(int state){
    switch(state){
        case 0:
            this.state = 0;
            this.speed = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            this.state = 1;
            this.speed = 0;
            break;
        case 2 :
            this.state = 2;
            break;
        case 3 :
            this.state = 3;
            this.speed = 0;
            break;
        case 4 :
            this.state = 4;
            this.speed = 0;
            this.fuel = 0;
            break;    

    }
}

public void accelerate(int v){


   if(this.state == 0 || this.state == 3 || this.state == 4){
      v = 0;
      this.speed = v;                  

    }

   if(this.fuel != 0 && this.state != 4 || this.state != 3){ 
       if(v > 200 || this.speed == 200){
           if(this.fuel < 30){
               this.speed = 200;
               this.state = 2;
            }
           else{
            this.speed = 200;
            this.state = 2;
            this.state -= 2;
           }
               }
               else{
                   this.speed += v;
                   this.fuel -= 2;
                   this.state = 2;
                }
            }                        
        }

public void Stop(){
    while(this.state == 2){
        this.speed = 0;
        this.state = 1;
    }

  }

public void Crash(){
    if(this.state == 2){
        this.state = 3;
        this.speed = 0;
    }
}

}
```

Also, it's not asked on the exercise but how could I make the state visible with strings, instead of numbers?

I'm also asked to test this by using a System void main, but I'm not entirely sure how to make the connections. Any help?

Comment: The state should really be an enum. If you're not supposed to use enums yet, at least declare constants for your states, and use the constant names, rather then 1, 2, 3, 4, 5: `if (state == STOPPED)` is much clearer than `if (state == 1)`.

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }` is the entry point for many Java programs. It's where the program starts, and `String[] args` is any command-line arguments passed in to the program when it's started. In `main()`, you'll want to create a `new Car();`, then call different methods from the `Car` class. But now I have to ask; if you're not using a `main()` method, how are you running your code?

Comment: @JBNizet It sounds like PBRD is pretty early in their first Java course. Let's not confuse them with code quality best practices before they even understand the basics.

Comment: Also, respect the Java naming conventions: methods start with a lowercase letter. `setState()` shouldn't exist. and the local variable MaxSpeed should also be a constant. It's useless as a local variable of the constructor.

Comment: @MartinCarney that's why I suggested to declare constants instead of using an enum. That will *help* the OP writing and understanding his own code.

Comment: It's been 4 weeks since I started and I haven't seen enums yet. I'm testing my code using BlueJ and using it as an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is in `if (this.fuel != 0 && this.state != 4 || this.state != 3) {`,  which is line 52 for me. It looks like you made a copy-paste error copying from line 46. `this.state != 4` will evaluate to true except if state is 4. `this.state != 3` will evaluate to true except if state is 3. `this.state != 4 || this.state != 3` will always evaluate to true because one of the two will always be true. That is, `(true || anything) == true`. Change the `||` to `&&`.

Next, if your car is ever given an odd number for fuel, it will run forever. Every line that decreases the fuel does so by 2, and you're checking if `fuel != 0`. If fuel is at -1, then `fuel != 0` is true, even though your car is supposedly out of fuel. Instead, you want to check that fuel is positive, i.e. `fuel > 0`.

Finally, line 61 you're changing `this.state` instead of `this.fuel`.

I'd recommend changing all the places in `accelerate(v)`, `stop()`, and `crash()` where you set `this.state == s` to instead call `setState(s)` so that `setState()` handles side-effect changes (like fuel and speed) instead of duplicating the same functionality in each of those three places.

> Also, it's not asked on the exercise but how could I make the state visible with strings, instead of numbers?

Create a method which returns a String according to the Car's state. Something like:

```
public String getStateName() {
    switch (state) {
        case 0: return "turned off";
        case 1: return "stopped";
        case 2: return "accelerating";
        case 3: return "not functional";
        case 4: return "no fuel";
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

(note that each `case` will `return` a value, which is why they don't need a `break` at the end of each case.)

> I'm also asked to test this by using a System void main, but I'm not entirely sure how to make the connections. Any help?

Add a method `public static void main(String[] args) { ... }`, which is the entry point into your program. Create a `new Car()` variable, then call this Car's various methods and use `System.out.println(...)` to print the information you need out to the console. Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // make a Car.
    Car myCar = new Car();
    myCar.printCarStatus();

    // turn the car on
    myCar.setState(1);
    myCar.printCarStatus();

    // speed up
    myCar.accelerate(20);
    myCar.printCarStatus();

    // brake
    myCar.stop();
    myCar.printCarStatus();

    // speed up, put the pedal to the metal
    myCar.accelerate(1000); // car tops out at 200
    myCar.printCarStatus();

    // lost control of my car, crash
    myCar.crash();
    myCar.printCarStatus();
}

public void printCarStatus() {
    System.out.println("State: " + this.state);
    System.out.println("Fuel: " + this.fuel);
    System.out.println("Speed: " + this.speed);
    System.out.println(); // prints an empty line so we don't get entries mixed up.
}
```

But write your own `main()` method, don't just copy mine. Remember - you're taking the class to learn, so try things out and experiment. If you just copy my example and paste it into your code, you're cheating yourself. Good luck out there!

Comment: Thanks a lot for telling me what I got wrong. Now, I'm trying to make the main class work. But whenever I call a "this.anything" I get an error that symbol can not be found.

Comment: If you're calling `this.anything` in `main()`, that's the problem. `main()` is a static method, but all of the methods for your `Car` class other than it are instance methods. That means you need to call them from a `Car` object. Thus in my `main()`, I start with `Car myCar = new Car();` and then I use `myCar` instead of `this` for all subsequent actions.

Comment: That means the method of printing must be on the car object?

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry, that was unclear. I was lazy and put my `main()` in the Car class rather than its own. Also my unedited answer I mistakenly forgot to call `printCarStatus()` from `myCar`, instead calling it as if it were static.

Comment: I did it. I finished the exercise on time! Thanks for your help! Now I'm getting the hang of using methods and validating. Somehow I got confused between the "and's" and "or's"

But yeah, I fixed the validating and now my "car" doesn't repair itself or takes fuel loans... hahaha..

Thanks guys!